# Having multiple solutions, one with a dependency and one without

Tags: dynamic, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I have come up with a solution which is independent of any dependencies, now I want to extend this solution with Click Dimension. My goal is to have two solutions :

- Base solution
- Base solution with Click Dimension dependency

For this approach, I made a new instance and exported the base solution there and installed click dimension.

Now my problem is I want to use one code in both the development but I think this approach will fail for example I develop something in Click Dimension environment and want to prevent some plugin code from a base solution than using one code in both instances might fail.

I would like to hear from you what is the best approach here to have two solutions.

Answer (score 0):

What you are saying is you want a solution which can be put into your Base solution which can be extended in the Base + Click Dim Solution
you will have to create a 2nd solution in your base Solution. So a 2nd model which doesn't have click dimension dependency, but can be extended. this means that when you install it in a environment with Click Dims, you can create a new model there, reference Click dim, and extend the methods.

Ideally you should put these interfacing methods into your base solution.

Comment: yes but this approach will work for csharp code and not for javascript. Or maybe but I dont know how to do it in javascript because as far I know iexplorer does not support classes.

Comment: You have tagged Dynamics 365 in here. The solution I proposed was for a standard D365 Finance and operations environment.